# What is using a function within between the two tags of a React component called?

Tags: reactjs

For example, in the `@headless-ui/react` library, the `Listbox.Option` can pass down the values of its internal props through the following:

```
<Listbox.Option>
    {({ selected }) => (/* some component here */)}
</Listbox.Option>
```

What is this called, and how can one write code that achieves a similar function?

Answer (score 3):

It's called a [render prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html).

You can easily make your own render props by using the `children` component as a function.

```js
function MyComponent({ children }) {
  // ...
  return <div>{children(...)}</div>
}

<MyComponent>
  {(...) => ...}
</MyComponent>
```

Answer (score 2):

This pattern is named rather descriptively: [Function-as-Child-Component](https://reactpatterns.js.org/docs/function-as-child-component/). It's a variation on render-props.

Authoring a component that works in this way can be as simple as literally calling the `children` prop passed in (e.g. `children()`), though it's recommended to at least run `React.Children.only(children)()` to ensure that `children` is not an array.

[React.Children.only documentation here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenonly), for reference.